# C# Windows Service While loop

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a problem with a windows service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    while (!File.Exists(@"C:\\Users\\john\\logOn\\oauth_url.txt"))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
...
```

I have to wait for a particular file, thus while loop is necessary, but the service will not be able to start with loop like this. What I can do to have a running service and a mechanism that checks if a file exists ?

Comment: Don't do this in an OnStart. And don't use \\, the separator is \

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to have a timer [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) in your service.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

In the constructor add the handler for the `Elapsed` event:

```
timer.Interval = 1000; //miliseconds
timer.Elapsed += TimerTicked;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Then in the `OnStart` method start that timer:

```
timer.Start();
```

In the event handler do your work:

```
private static void TimerTicked(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\john\logOn\oauth_url.txt"))
        return;

    //If the file exists do stuff, otherwise the timer will tick after another second.
}
```

A minimal service class will look somewhat like this:

```
public class FileCheckServivce : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase  
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    public FileCheckServivce()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTicked;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    private static void TimerTicked(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\john\logOn\oauth_url.txt")) 
            return;

        //If the file exists do stuff, otherwise the timer will tick after another second.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using FileSystemWatcher as that is exactly what it is intended for, to monitor changes on the filesystem. Once event is raised on a folder, you can check if that particular file exists.

The default example in MSDN actually shows monitoring of .txt file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx